# Finding Time Complexity

Tags: time, runtime, time-complexity, complexity-theory

For functions, n^k and c^n , what is the asymptotic relationship between these functions? Assume that k ≥ 1,and c ≥ 1 are constant.

1. n^k is O(c^n)
2. n^k is Ω(c^n)
3. n^k is Θ(c^n)
4. None of the above

My thought : when c=1 then for every value, n^k > c^n and when c>1 then C^n > n^k.
so, answer suggested is 3. n^k is Θ(c^n).

Is the thought and my answer correct ? Requesting for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in fact two answers to this question, depending on the value of `c`:

- If `c = 1`, then `c^n = 1^n = 1`. `n^k` for `k ≥ 1` will obviously outgrow this, so the answer would be **(2)**.
- If `c > 1`, then the exponential `c^n` *far* outgrows *any* polynomial term, i.e. the answer would be **(1)**.

Note that **(3)** is never true.